# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: (Read file from Github)

Tags: python

I have a geojson file stored on my laptop and on github. I have no trouble reading the file off of my laptop:

```
obj = r'Teacher Quality Gap - Washington\Geo\1988\experience_gap_bins_0.102-0.805.geojson'
with open(obj) as f:
    geo = json.load(f)
```

But when I read this from [github](https://github.com/otteheng/Teacher-Quality-Gaps-Dash/blob/master/1988/experience_gap_bins_0.102-0.805.geojson?short_path=35cb681) I get an `OSError`.

```
base_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/otteheng/Teacher-Quality-Gaps-Dash/master/'

year = '1988'
binz = 'experience_gap_bins_0.102-0.805'
with open(base_url + year + '/' + binz + '.geojson?_sm_au_=iMV8R4JMtDJsZNt2') as f:
    geo = json.load(f)
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Python 3.6 on windows.

Comment: The open function opens a file in the local filesystem. To open a URL use something like the requests or urllib modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open) can only open local files. Or more precisely, files from a filesystem accessible to the running process (so a network mounted filesystem would still be accessible). It can't "open" files from a http server or ftp server etc. Like you're trying to do.

Check out the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package for something which can do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Using the requests library fixed the problem. The error message led me down a rabbit hole looking for any issues with escape characters, etc and other problems people had on their local systems. Now I know why. Thanks!